# CAML query help needed - need system time plus or minus a number of minutes

Tags: caml

Is there a way to replace the date / times in the query below with the current date/time plus or minus a number of minutes?

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <And>
      <Geq>
        <FieldRef Name="SendDate" />
          <Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2011-01-01T15:55:52Z</Value>
      </Geq>
      <Leq>
        <FieldRef Name="SendDate" />
        <Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2011-12-31T15:56:29Z</Value>
      </Leq>
    </And>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do with minutes. CAML support `OffsetDays` as below

```
<FieldRef Name="SendDate" />
<Value Type="DateTime">
    <Today OffsetDays="-30" />
</Value>
```